# Parametrisation of the boundary of the image of $f(z) = e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function given by $f(z) = e^z$. How would you parametrise the boundary of the image $f(B(a,r))$ ($\partial f(B(a,r))$) with $B(a,r) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ being a sphere around $a \in \mathbb{C}$ with radius $r > 0$?

My hunch is that the boundary
$$
f(\partial B(a,r)) = \partial f(B(a,r))
$$
and I thought that would make it easier, but I couldn't prove it (because maybe it isn't even true). In that case it would just be 
$$
\gamma(\varphi) = e^{r e^{i \varphi}}
$$
with $\varphi \in [0, 2 \pi)$.
Furthermore, I tried messing with the fact that
$$
|e^z| = e^{|z| \cos(\arg(z))}
$$
and
$$
\arg(e^z) = |z| \sin(\arg(z)).
$$
Are there any tips/strategies? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $f(\partial B(a,r)) \not= \partial f(B(a,r))$.

Indeed, for $a=0$ and $r=4$, the boundary of $B(a,r)$ is mapped to a curve that looks like a limaçon and has self-intersections.
The self-intersections occur for $t=\theta$ and $t=2\pi-\theta$, where $\theta=\arcsin(\pi/4)$. These are found by solving $Im(f(z))=0$.

[image]

Comment: Ah yes I see, that saves me a lot of time! Thanks!